# Extract a date from a dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a dict like this:

```
SHOPS_AND_ORDERNUM = {
'Shop - Produce - 20180212.xlsx': 1334, 
'Shop - Organic - 20180223.xlsx': 8893, 
'Shop - Fresh - 20180226.xlsx': 5557,
'Shop - Dairy - 20180227.xlsx': 3870 
}
```

I want to extract the dates from the dict above into the form: 
DD-MM-YYYY

I am new to regular expressions, and my attempts keep failing.

I have started something like this:

```
for i, j in DATA_FILES_AND_SO.items():
     m = re.search(some_logic, i)
     if m:
     found = m.group(1)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: what is `some_logic`

Comment: What do you mean _"extract the dates from the dict above into the form: DD-MM-YYYY"_? You want to replace the keys in the dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format does not change, you can use this (no need of RegEx):

```
SHOPS_AND_ORDERNUM = {
    'Shop - Produce - 20180212.xlsx': 1334,
    'Shop - Organic - 20180223.xlsx': 8893,
    'Shop - Fresh - 20180226.xlsx': 5557,
    'Shop - Dairy - 20180227.xlsx': 3870
}

for item in SHOPS_AND_ORDERNUM:
    date = item.split('.xlsx')[0][-8:]
    print(date)
```

Output:

```
20180212
20180223
20180226
20180227
```

Now, to get the date in the format you want, you can use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module, like this:

```
for item in SHOPS_AND_ORDERNUM:
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(item.split('.xlsx')[0][-8:], '%Y%m%d').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    print(date)
```

Output:

```
12-02-2018
23-02-2018
26-02-2018
27-02-2018
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex:

```
import re
SHOPS_AND_ORDERNUM = {
'Shop - Produce - 20180212.xlsx': 1334, 
'Shop - Organic - 20180223.xlsx': 8893, 
'Shop - Fresh - 20180226.xlsx': 5557,
'Shop - Dairy - 20180227.xlsx': 3870 
}
new_data = {(lambda x:(x[7:], x[4:6], x[:4]))(re.findall('\d+', a)[0]):b for a, b in SHOPS_AND_ORDERNUM.items()}
```

Output:

```
{('2', '02', '2018'): 1334, ('3', '02', '2018'): 8893, ('6', '02', '2018'): 5557, ('7', '02', '2018'): 3870}
```

Or, instead of tuples:

```
new_data = {'{}-{}-{}'.format(*a[::-1]):b for a, b in new_data.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'2018-02-2': 1334, '2018-02-7': 3870, '2018-02-3': 8893, '2018-02-6': 5557}
```

Comment: Using ` '-'.join()` to add hyphens would be cleaner and more efficient

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `datetime` module to get your required date format

**Ex:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import datetime
SHOPS_AND_ORDERNUM = {
'Shop - Produce - 20180212.xlsx': 1334,
'Shop - Organic - 20180223.xlsx': 8893,
'Shop - Fresh - 20180226.xlsx': 5557,
'Shop - Dairy - 20180227.xlsx': 3870
}

for k,v in SHOPS_AND_ORDERNUM.items():
    print datetime.datetime.strptime(k.split("-")[-1].rstrip(".xlsx").strip(), "%Y%m%d"  ).strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

**Output:**

```
27-02-2018
26-02-2018
23-02-2018
12-02-2018
```

**MoreInfo**

1. `k.split("-")[-1].rstrip(".xlsx").strip()`  #to get the date string from key. ex: `20180212`
2. `datetime.datetime.strptime` #to convert datetime to your required format. `"%d-%m-%Y"`

Answer (score 3):

```
import datetime

dates = []

for i, j in DATA_FILES_AND_SO.items():
     date = i[-13:-5]
     dates.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic regex you're looking for is ([0-9]+)(?=.)\g.  You can play around with it on https://regex101.com/.

For date string conversion, you can use the Carbon library, such as

`$newDateString = \Carbon::parse('20180212')->format('DD-MM-YYYY');`

See also the [Carbon Docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).